# How can I create a commit that rolls back another one?

Tags: git, git-history-rewrite

For simplicity, let's create a repository with two commits only:

```sh
mkdir somedir
cd somedir
git init
echo hello > somefile
git add somefile
git commit -m 'first'
echo world >> somefile
git commit -am 'second'
```

For clarity, at this point `git log --oneline` returns

```sh
fd5b1ce (HEAD -> master) second
f621ab9 first
```

What I want to get to is the following

```sh
xxxxxxx (HEAD -> master) third
fd5b1ce second
f621ab9 first
```

with `somefile` in `third` having the same content as `somefile` in `first`.

I could certainly do `git cherry-pick master~` (here `master` is `fd5b1ce`) and resolve the conflict totally in favour of `first`, but maybe there's a cleaner approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> commit that rolls back another one?

That seems a good fit for [git revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)

```
git revert <second commit>
```

But that apply to all files from second commit (being reverted)

> with `somefile` in third having the same content as somefile in first.

If you need to revert only one file, use [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore).

```
git restore -SW -s=<first commit> -- somefile
```